# IntelliJ and Java default path for reading files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm a bit confused how default file searching path is set both in IntelliJ and in Java in general. I'm including IntelliJ as a tag, because this IDE for sure modify/adds some additional paths to search for.

Consider following, dummy code:

```
    File ff = new File("test.txt");
    if(ff.exists() && !ff.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Exist");
        LabelReader lr = new LabelReader(ff);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Missing");
    }
```

In IntelliJ this will work only, if `test.txt` will be placed in project top-most directory (i.e. alongside with `src`, `pom.xml` e.c.t)

**First Question**:
which setting is responsible for adding/modifying this dummy starting path?

Now `ClassLoader` and it's `getResource`:

```
    ClassLoader cl = DayTwoMain.class.getClassLoader();
    URL pathURL = cl.getResource("test.txt");
    File ff = new File(pathURL.getPath());
    if(ff.exists() && !ff.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Exist");
        LabelReader lr = new LabelReader(ff);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Missing");
    }
```

Will produce `NullPointerException` due to `URL` being set to `null`, but following dummy invocation:

```
    ClassLoader cl = DayTwoMain.class.getClassLoader();
    URL pathURL = cl.getResource("");
```

Gives the URL that points to `[ProjectRoot]/target/classes`

**Second question**:
Why `ClassLoader` path is set to post-build directory? Is it related with actual JVM starting from this directory after compilation of sources? How and where it can be altered/modified?

Now with resources. I assume, that IntelliJ/Maven projects files, images, configs and other static assess shall be stored in resources folder. So, folder marked as resources root in IntelliJ shall be copied as-is to target destination, but for me this is not the case, target contains only classes folder, no resources were copied. I must added manually section with resources to `pom.xml` like below:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/*</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

to force IntelliJ to copy it to target.

**Third Question**
Isn't this a task to be done by IntelliJ automatically? Whole those huge IDEs are ment to automate those tasks by fun and joy of point&click? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: **Working directory** setting in the run/debug configuration affects the default path your file will be read from.

Comment: `test.txt` is missing in the output path, hence the NPE. It has to be placed into the resources root to be copied into the classpath, you can find hundreds of similar questions and answers on SO.

Comment: Classloader loads resources from classpath, classpath in a project you develop in the IDE is the output path. It should work by default with the default Maven directories layout. You don't need to add this directory to resources. If it doesn't work, please file a bug with a sample project to reproduce at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: You seem to confuse the working directory and the class path. These are quite different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

`new File("test.txt")` will attempt to read the file from whatever is the current working directory. In IntelliJ each run configuration allows to specify the Working Directory option as per [documentation: Creating and Editing Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html)

This can be be platform specific e.g. if you have a custom run configuration with `java` executable launched on windows through a `cmd /c java` than `cmd` configuration e.g. registry entries applies.

Furthermore if you use a plugin specific Run Configuration e.g. Maven or Gradle they may apply their own rules and settings. Especially in a multi-module project for child modules the path could be different from parent module.

This is completely different from your questions which are related to `ClassLoader` and Maven resource filtering. This things are not managed by IntelliJ, the IDE only makes it convenient to run with a Run Configuration.